# Hacer fórmula recorriendo un dataframe en python con pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Hola la verdad que me ha costado mucho expresar el problema que tengo, espero puedan ayudarme.
el tema es que necesito recorrer una dataframe con datos ( primera imagen) mi profesor me dijo que usara iloc para sacar las columnas, pero no puedo hacer el calculo que tengo en la formula ( imagen 2)
la verdad que estoy al borde del llanto.

[image: matriz data frame python pandas]

mi formula que intento hacer es recorrer toda la matriz, y tomar cada dato y hacer lo que esta en la formula:

```
for caderaX, tobilloY, caderaY, tobilloX in zip(caderaX, tobilloY, caderaY, tobilloX):
    result = math.sqrt(((caderaX-tobilloX)**2)+((caderaY-tobilloY)**2))
    print("Resultado es:", result)
```

Answer (score 0):

Con apply puedes hacer operaciones:

```
Data[['operacion']]=Data.apply(lambda x:operacion(x['caderaX'],x['tobilloY'],x['caderaY'],x['tobilloX']),axis=1)

def operacion(cx,ty,cy,tx):
    return math.sqrt(((cx-tx)**2)+((cy-ty)**2))
```

o  tambien:

```
Data['operacion']=operacion(Data['caderaX'],Data['tobilloY'],Data['caderaY'],Data['tobilloX'])
```

Answer (score 0):

Usar un `for` con pandas para realizar ésta operación es un delito :). Es infinitamente más simple y eficiente vectorizar:

```
import io
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


data = io.StringIO((
   "CADERA X,CADERA Y,RODILLA X,RODILLA Y,TOBILLO X,TOBILLO Y\n"
   "0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0\n"
   "0.0,0.92,0.23,0.69,-0.23,0.46\n"
   "-0.23,3.90,0.23,1.61,-0.92,1.15\n"
   "-0.69,5.51,0.0,2.99,-1.84,2.30\n")
   )

df = pd.read_csv(data)
```

> **El uso de `io` es solo para hacer el ejemplo reproducible emulando un csv, en tu caso lee de la fuente que tengas**.

```
results = (
    np.sqrt(
        (df["CADERA X"] - df["TOBILLO X"]) ** 2 +
        (df["CADERA Y"] - df["TOBILLO Y"]) ** 2)
    )
```

La variable `results` es una `Serie`:

> ```
> >>> results
>
> 0    0.000000
> 1    0.514296
> 2    2.835242
> 3    3.409780
> dtype: float64
> ```

Si quieres imprimirla con el formato que muestras:

> ```
> >>> for result in results: 
>         print(f"El resultado es: {result}")
>
> El resultado es: 0.0
> El resultado es: 0.5142956348249517
> El resultado es: 2.8352424940382086
> El resultado es: 3.4097800515575782
> ```

Si quieres que sea una columna del propio DataFrame simplemente :

```
df["results"] = (
    np.sqrt(
        (df["CADERA X"] - df["TOBILLO X"]) ** 2 +
        (df["CADERA Y"] - df["TOBILLO Y"]) ** 2)
    )
```

Si no quieres aplicarla sobre todo el rango de filas, puedes usar `iloc`, pero no en un `for`:

```
df["results"] = (
    np.sqrt(
        (df.iloc[0: 273, 0] - df.iloc[0: 273, 4]) ** 2 +
        (df.iloc[0: 273, 1] - df.iloc[0: 273, 5]) ** 2)
    )
```